# R: Loop function over columns in a R script

Tags: r, function, loops, multiple-columns

Assume we have following table where we have each two pairs of variables to be tested with each other (the original table has far more columns):http://pastebin.com/igeMTaSB

How can I create a loop in R so that it applies a function each one or two rows in a script?

**Example Code:**

```
library(urca)
library(lmtest)

# Load data (See link)

table = read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",")
table = data.frame(table)
table

# For each column in the table (a1-d2), do
VARselect(table$column,lag.max = 10,type="both")

# For each two sequent pairs in the table (a1+a2, b1+b2,c1+c2,d1+d2), do
grangertest(table$a1, table$a2, order = 1, na.action = na.omit)
```

Comment: For the one variable case, use `sapply` or `lapply`: `lapply(table, function(i) VARselect(i,lag.max = 10,type="both"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one variable case, use `sapply` or `lapply`, for example:

```
myVarSel <- lapply(table, function(i) VARselect(i,lag.max = 10,type="both"))
```

If your pairs of variables are located adjacently (columns 1,2 and 3,4 and 5,6), you can use `lapply` as follows:

```
myGtests <- lapply(seq(1, 5, 2), function(i) grangertest(table[[i]], table[[i+1]], order = 1,
                                             na.action = na.omit))
```

If the variables are arranged in a different manner, you can use tools like `grep` on the `names(df)` to locate them. for extraction in `lapply`.

The `lapply` function returns a list, where each element is the result of the corresponding function.